# Include es5 lib into the stencil web component

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs, stencil-component

I have an external library that is written in the old IIFE style. I have a web component which uses this lib inside. This web component was created with stencil.
Now if I use my web component in some project, I have to include component js file and this external library to the index.html via src file. How can I include this library to the component's compiled code? Is it possible without re-writing it to the es6 module?

This is how my code looks now (in the index.html):

```
<script src="./myMathLib.js"></script>
<script src="./myWebComponent.js"></script>
```

I want to have it like this:

```
<script src="./myWebComponent.js"></script>
```

This is the code of my component:

```
import {Component, Prop} from '@stencil/core';

declare var myMathLib: any;

@Component({
    tag: 'my-component',
    shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

    @Prop() name: string;
    @Prop() age: number;

    render() {
        return <div>
            The age of {this.name} is: {myMathLib.calculate(this.age)}
        </div>;
    }
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "h"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "types/jsx.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This is my stencil.config.ts:

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'mycomponent',
  outputTargets:[
    { type: 'dist' },
    { type: 'docs' },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null // disable service workers
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Depending on how the external library is written you might be able to `import` it in your component. Do you have a link to the library?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the root of your project, there should be a stencil.config.ts file. In there you can specify copy tasks. You can read here how to do this: https://stenciljs.com/docs/config#copy

After you set that up correctly and your ../assets/ folder is being copied to your build folder.

You need to copy your all the external js file inside assets folder.

In your render method you can directly refer js file from /assets/

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I figured out that the best option is to use `globalScript` property from stencil.config.

I added my library to the assets folder and then added the following line to my stencil.config.ts file:

```
globalScript:'src/assets/myMathLib.js'
```

After it, I was able to use myMathLib.calculate(this.age) in the code of the component.